# Why there is unusually big leaves on a single tree branch

Tags: botany

I have a freshly planted katsura tree - in general it has leaves that are 1-2 inches in diameter.
[image: normal leaves]
But one single branch has grown disproportionally longer than others and leaves on this branch are up to 4 inches in diameter
[image: leaves]
Why is that? Should I trim it?

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer the bit about whether or not you should trim it (there is a landscape/gardening beta here which may be better). But what kind of 'why' answer are you looking for? One which explains it in terms of physiology / evolution / biochemistry / environment interaction?

Comment: With many plants, including Katsura, the juvenile foliage is different from the mature foliage. With Katsura the juvenile foliage has larger leaves.

Comment: The rest of new leaves are about the same size and structure as older leaves. Also no other branch has grew up THAT much - they added maybe a few inches but this one added 2 feet. I'm curios what may be the cause.